# Mixing logical OR and AND in ModSecurity/Coraza

Tags: mod-security

In ModSecurity (I'm actually using Coraza but it should be the same thing), how I can mix logical OR and AND? For example, I want a rule that denies the request if the source IP matches a list of CIDR ranges AND matches a list of host headers. It would be equivalent of:

```
if (srcIp in ['3.4.5.0/24', '2.3.4.0/24']) AND (host in ['foo.com', 'bar.com'])
  deny
```

I can achieve AND by chaining. For IP address this works:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:X-Forwarded-For "@ipMatch 3.4.5.0/24,2.3.4.0/24" "id:9,phase:1,chain"
```

But how to also match against multiple hosts in one rule?

I tried

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@pm bar.com baz.com" "id:10,phase:1,deny"
```

But this also matches against `abar.com` and `bar.coma`

Multiple chained rules per host are treated as an AND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@within` operator matches against a list of values:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@within bar.com,baz.com" "id:10,phase:1,deny"
```